# Excel VBA - Copy and paste row to a new blank row, starting in predefined location

Tags: excel, vba, paste

VBA newbie here, trying to learn by doing. I have the following code, which on the whole is doing exactly what I want it to:

```
'define source range
Dim SourceRange As Range
Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Range("B2:D2")
'find next free cell in destination sheet
Dim NextFreeCell As Range
Set NextFreeCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)    
'copy & paste
SourceRange.Copy
NextFreeCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
NextFreeCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'delete text box
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.Goto Reference:="R2C4"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
```

The source range B2:D2 are data entry boxes (DATE/TIME/FREETEXT).

When it pastes to the next free row, it currently pastes directly underneath the original data entry boxes, so in B3, then B4 etc.

How would I get it to commence somewhere lower, say for example B10?

Comment: The "easy" way is to add a header of some sort in `B9`. If that's not an option, then you could always check the `.Row` of `NextFreeCell` and if it's less than `10` use `B10` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I *think* I understand so will give it a go re: header. It would be handy to 'freeze' the top section with the free text boxes in so it's always accessible and the numerous extra rows below to be scroll-able, so this would work for me. I'm not sure I altogether understand your second suggestion so would be super grateful for any further explanation? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow-up to my comment:

> The "easy" way is to add a header of some sort in `B9`. If that's not an option, then you could always check the `.Row` of `NextFreeCell` and if it's less than `10` use `B10` instead.

You could potentially do something similar like this, changing:

```vb
Set NextFreeCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
```

to

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log")
    If IsEmpty(.Range("B10").Value) Then
        Set NextFreeCell = .Range("B10")
    Else
        Set NextFreeCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
End With
```

which would ensure that if `B10` is empty, it is populated first. On subsequent runs, `NextFreeCell` will always be underneath.

Comment: Thank you. I did this and I got a 'variable not defined' error. So, I removed the 'Option Explicit' from the top of the code and it worked first time. But, it won't add any further entries on subsequent runs and returns *Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error*

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `IF` statement right after you first set `NextFreeCell` which would look something like (assuming you want results starting in column B)...

```
'define source range
Dim SourceRange As Range
Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Range("B2:D2")
'find next free cell in destination sheet
Dim NextFreeCell As Range
Set NextFreeCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
If NextFreeCell.Row < 10 Then
    Set NextFreeCell = NextFreeCell.Offset(10 - NextFreeCell.Row, 0)
End If
'copy & paste
SourceRange.Copy
NextFreeCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
NextFreeCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'delete text box
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.Goto Reference:="R2C4"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
```

Comment: Thanks, I did experiment with that previously but it causes a gap of 7 rows between every extra row that is inserted thereafter, when I really want them to follow consecutively. I basically want the 'free text' boxes to stand alone at the top of the sheet, with a gap (for aesthetic purposes) before them recommence a few rows lower, but thereafter continue one after another.

Comment: Sorry about that...from you post I didn't get that this was inside of a loop. I'll edit my response to reflect that.